# Add JQuery to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I want to add some global JavaScript  to Sharepoint 2010.
So I put JQuery to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS` and my script to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\Scripts\` and now I have no clue where to put `<script src="/_layouts/jquery-min.js">`
Can anyone help with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put `<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/Scripts/jquery-min.js"></script>` in master page to access this javascript globally in all pages.

Or you can put that script tag in your **custom webpart** / **content editor webpart** / **script editor webpart** to access that script only for that webpart only.

Comment: I have three of master pages: default.master, minimal.master and v4.master.  Changing any of them doesn't affect anything, i.e. I don't see my changes in  default page  source

Comment: Add this script tag in your current master page. By putting this script, Which functionality you want to achieve?

Comment: so putting this globally doesn't change anything. you should change master pages for each subsite

Answer (score 0):

I discuss how to get started with jQuery (including how to deploy and reference the library) in this conference session: [JavaScript and jQuery for SharePoint Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbE9ytxabzs)